# How to run application have file .js

Tags: ckeditor, editor, text-editor

I searching some application text editor and I a little software no have .exe. 
Ex: ckeditor,...
It has file .js . So can I run it? And how to run it? Thanks very much!

Comment: CKEditor is an editor that you embed into a website, not an actual text editor for your computer.

Comment: Can you guide me how to run it? Thanks!

Comment: The website should include details about how to embed the text editor into the website that you are creating. If you are looking for a text editor for your computer, try something like Notepad++, Vim, or Sublime Text.